# Determine with Camera2 when a lens is monochrome in APIs < 29

Tags: android, android-camera2, monochrome

For Android API >= 29 I use the next snipped to determine when a lens is monocrhome:

```
public boolean isMono(@NonNull final CameraCharacteristics characteristics) {
    final Integer value = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_COLOR_FILTER_ARRANGEMENT);

    return (value != null)
            && ((value == CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_COLOR_FILTER_ARRANGEMENT_MONO)
                || (value == CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_COLOR_FILTER_ARRANGEMENT_NIR));
}
```

Both [SENSOR_INFO_COLOR_FILTER_ARRANGEMENT_MONO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#SENSOR_INFO_COLOR_FILTER_ARRANGEMENT_MONO) and [SENSOR_INFO_COLOR_FILTER_ARRANGEMENT_NIR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#SENSOR_INFO_COLOR_FILTER_ARRANGEMENT_NIR) were introduced in API 29.

What would be the way to determine if a lens is monochrome for APIs < 29?

In API 28 [REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MONOCHROME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MONOCHROME) can be used to know when a camera lens is monochrome, but in my test devices I'm not getting such capability for known monochrome lenses. I don't known if it is due to an incorrect manufacturer's implementation.

As for APIs < 28 I couldn't find any way to check.